# Default template parameter in constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, templates, default, parameters

So I have this piece of code and out of convenience I want the default parameter for its constructor be of the int kind and 0. (I have more parameters in a class of my project and one of them is optional and I don't want to write the constructor twice because its big)

```
class mama{
    public:
    template<typename x> mama(x i=int(0)){}
};

int main(){
    mama x;
}
```

This doesn't work because it says it can't find the constructor so is there another way I can do this?

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘mama::mama()'
note: candidates are: mama::mama(const mama&)
```

Answer (score 5):

Note that default template parameters are not allowed for function templates. Why not create a class template?

```
template <class T=int>
class mama{
    public:
    mama<T>(T i=0){}
};

int main(){
    mama<> x; // no argument based template parameter deduction possible
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Refactor your constructor into a private initialization function and wrapper constructors, then add a default, like so:

```
class mama {
  private:
    template<typename x> void init(x i) { /* ... */ }
  public:
    template<typename x> mama(x i) { init(i); }
    mama() { init((int)0); }
};
```

Comment: The fact that your ctor is templated is a strong hint for me to templatize the whole class. YMMV!

Comment: Probably; I can't imagine how a templated constructor like this would be useful without templatizing the class, but this gives what the original question asked for, and someone else covered making the class a template :)

Comment: Actually templatized constructor is very useful. For example boost::shared_ptr, boost::any, and may implementation of handle-body or similar pattern uses this technique.

Comment: +1 this solves the second issue of not having to copy/paste chunks of code to provide multiple similar constructors by refactoring the initialization code into separate method and call it from constructor with required parameters. More flexible to maintain.

Answer (score -1):

Default value works just like overload, so...

```
class mama{
public:
    template<typename x> mama(x i){}
    mama(int i = 0) {}
};
```

When you create mama with no argument, the construct with default int is matched before any templated constructor.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't avoid the code duplication.  Csiz wanted a single constructor.

Comment: If you don't want to write the constructor body twice factor it into a function, like what bdonlan suggested. However, if you later want to specialize mama::mama(int), with bdonlan's solution (having a default constructor with no argument instead of constructor with int and default to 0) you cannot do it without adding another constructor.